# Como detectar uma determinada sequencia de números em javascript?

Tags: javascript

No campo cadastro de endereço, tenho o campo cep.
Nesse campo cep, preciso fazer algumas validações:

1 - Não permitir o usuário digitar uma sequencia com dois numeros alternados entre si:

```
EX 1: "12121212"
EX 2: "12312312"
```

2 - Não permitir o usuário digitar uma sequencia de um determinado numero:

```
EX: "111111111"
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?
Não consegui fazer um regex que tratasse as duas situações.

Comment: Sempre será sequência de 2 ?

Comment: pode ser uma sequencia de 3 também, é o máximo que vou bloquear.

Comment: Para o segundo exemplo esse caso entraria como errado ? "1102039020392" com relação ao "11" ...

Comment: não quero permitir ceps assim: 111111111 222222222 33333333
Não quero deixa o usuario colocar um cep invalido

Comment: https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

Comment: Funcionou a resposta que coloquei pra você @durtto ?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode validar as repetições com a seguinte expressão:
`/([0-9]{2,3})\1/g`

Ela irá avaliar se existe grupos de 2 ou 3 algarismos repetidos, ou seja : `1212` ou `123123`

Exemplo:

```js
var cep = document.querySelector("input[name=cep]");


function fazRegex(){
 var reg = /([0-9]{2,3})\1/g;
  
 
  if(reg.test(cep.value))
   document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML = "Errado";
  else
   document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML = "Certo";
}

cep.addEventListener("keyup", fazRegex);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="cep" onkeyup="fazRegex()"/>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Veja também no [jsFindle](https://jsfiddle.net/bj98nwfg/11/)

Caso deseje testar a expresão mais a fundo aconselho vivamente a visitar o site:

[regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Não tratou a questão da repetição.

Comment: Fiz edição na resposta, veja se vai de acordo com os seus requisitos.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro criei uma função para verificar se há duplicados na string, que funciona da seguinte maneira: verifica na string passada se os números contém a repetição ( usando a referência anterior ) para o caso de repetição de 2 números.

Depois criei uma para verificar conteúdo repetido, onde usei um reduce no conteúdo; peguei a primeira posição e verifiquei se todas as outras são iguais a ela, caso sim, retorna verdadeiro...

No final verifico a negação de existir duplicados e existir todos os repetidos para assim ser uma string válida.

```js
var str1 = "121212122";
var str2 = "111111111";
var str3 = "123456789";

var is_repetidos = function(str) {
  return /([0-9])\1+/g.test(str);
}

var todos_iguais = function(str) {

  var conteudo_separado = str.split("");

  return conteudo_separado.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a == b;
  }, str[0]);

}

var is_valid = function(str) {
  return !(is_repetidos(str) || todos_iguais(str));
}

var dados = [str1, str2, str3];

for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
  console.log(dados[i] + " = " + is_valid(dados[i]))
}
```