# Bloquear sequencias de numeros input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não permitir o preenchimento de números em sequencia com espaços ou sem espaços, para evitar a adição de números de telefone.

Deve-se evitar sequencias como:

`99999999999
99 9 9999 9999`

e quaisquer outras que tenham mais de 7 números em sequencia.

O código faz um split e checa cada palavra, se tem mais de 7 caracteres, mas, logicamente está funcional apenas com números em sequencia sem espaço.

```
        $('input:text, textarea').keyup(function(){
            var num = $(this).val();
            var texto = num.split(" ");
            var a1 = num.split(" ");
            for (i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
            {

                var total_letras = a1[i].length;
                if($.isNumeric(a1[i])){
                    if( $(this).attr("id") !== 'input_cep' )//se id for cep, permitirá a digitação
                    {
                        if(total_letras > 7)
                        {           
                            $(this).val( num.substring(0, num.length - 2) );                        
                            $(this).addClass("input_bloqueado");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(this).removeClass("input_bloqueado");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Qual valor deve retornar ? Exemplo: 11999933333333 2 3333 1 77777 77777 1

Comment: @MauryDeveloper a ideia é bloquear a digitação de qualquer sequencia numérica maior que 7 digitos, com ou sem espaços

Comment: Você quer a resposta com Jquery ou Javascript puro? Obs: Odeio jQuery,mas vou tenta se quiser de outra forma.

Comment: sem preferencia, pode ser javascript

Comment: a textarea recebe mais que um 'campo'? o atributo `maxlength` não o ajuda?

Comment: `var reg = /([0-9]{7})/g; str.replace(" ","").replace(reg,"");` Remove sequencia de 7 numero seguidos

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295543/como-detectar-uma-determinada-sequencia-de-números-em-javascript Também é parecida

Comment: @MauryDeveloper salva no jsfiddle ou como resposta

Comment: Funcionou esse código?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/3ksdguw7/1/  - Parece haver interferencia com os textos ou não está corretamente implementado

Comment: Verdade. Vou tenta outra forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solulção:

```
$('#texto').keyup(function(){
    var reg = /((?:[1-9]\s*){7})/g;
    var texto = $(this).val();
    var result = texto.replace(reg,"********") ;

    $("#texto").val( result );

});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputText = window.textA || undefined

if( !inputText ){
input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for( i=0; i < input.length; ++i ) if( input[i].type.match(/text/) ) var inputText = input[i]
}

var textarea = window.textB || document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]

inputText.onkeyup = function(){ checkValueA(this) }
textarea.onkeyup  = function(){ checkValueB(this) }

var lastInputText, lastAreaText

function checkValueA(){
/* arguments[0].maxLength = 7 */
arguments[0].value = arguments[0].value.match(/[0-9]{1}$/)? arguments[0].value : (lastInputText||'')
lastInputText = arguments[0].value
if( arguments[0].value.match(/^[0-9]{7}$/) ) getNumber(arguments[0])
}

function checkValueB(){
/* arguments[0].maxLength = 7 */
arguments[0].value = arguments[0].value.match(/[0-9]{1}$/)? arguments[0].value : (lastAreaText ||'')
lastAreaText = arguments[0].value
if( arguments[0].value.match(/^[0-9]{7}$/) ) getNumber(arguments[0])
}

function getNumber(){
arguments[0].disabled = true
/* arguments[0].class = 'input_bloqueado' */
numero = +arguments[0].value

if( arguments[0].type == 'text'     ) labelA.innerHTML = '7 digitos sem espaços ou letras ' + labelA.innerText
if( arguments[0].type == 'textarea' ) labelB.innerHTML = '7 digitos sem espaços ou letras ' + labelB.innerText
if( arguments[0].type == 'text'     ) { labelA.style.color = "red"; labelA.appendChild( arguments[0] ) }
if( arguments[0].type == 'textarea' ) { labelB.style.color = "red"; labelB.appendChild( arguments[0] ) }
}
```

```html
<style>
input[type=text], textarea {
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 11pt;
width: 300px;
height: 46px;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
resize: none;
display: block;
}
</style>

<label id="labelA">( input text ):
<input type="text" placeholder="Telefone#" />
</label>
<label id="labelB">( textarea ):
<textarea placeholder="Telefone#"></textarea>
</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
form, input[type=number], input[type=submit] {
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 11pt;
border-radius: 4px;
display: block;
}

input[type=number] {
width: 300px;
height: 47px;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
-moz-appearance: textfield;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
background-color: red;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
Número de telefone: <input type="number" name="quantity" min="9000000" max="9999999" title="7 digitos">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

HTML <input type="number"> min max Attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp
HTML <input type="text"> pattern Attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Você esqueceu número tem telefone tem 9 dígitos? Exemplo: 988887777 min: 900000000 max:  999999999

Comment: "Deve-se evitar sequencias como: (...)(..) e quaisquer outras que tenham mais de 7 números em sequencia."..., na pergunta.

Comment: Mas está errada. Desculpe pelo voto contra. Numero são de 8 ou digito no mínimo

Comment: Em Angola são 14 : https://www.tellows.pt/num/00244922781982

Comment: Sim,mas falei no Brasil. Angola eu adoro esse país .

Comment: Em Cabo Verde são 7: https://www.paginasamarelas.cv/en/business-details/restaurants/2176518-restaurante-grill-luar

Comment: Vamos conversa chat? Essa conversa sai da pergunta.

Comment: Veja a solução de quem colocou a pergunta... /((?:[1-9]\s*){7})/g; ... 7(sete).

Comment: checa cada palavra, se tem mais de 7 caracteres. Você não viu o texto da pergunta? Outra coisa ela não pediu telefone e sim CEP. `if( $(this).attr("id") !== 'input_cep' )//se id for cep, permitirá a digitação`

Comment: 